# Resell reserved instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

I am willing to resell reserved instances in AWS in several region.

I read the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ri-market-selling-guide.html) but I still have few questions:

1. Who will be the effective buyer of the instance (in the financial documents), AWS or end customers?
2. How many money transfers will there be? I have about 10 instances for 4 months and I don't want to end up in the situation when I receive dozens of $10 transfers per each end user payment.

Many thanks!

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. End users. Why do you care anyway? You would sell through the AWS reservation service and the money would go through Amazon.
2. I don't understand the question. Are these reservations or spot requests? You would have at most 1 money transfer per instance reservation. How are your previous spot requests related to the instance reservations you want to sell?

Comment: I thought reselled reserved instances become spot ones on the second-hand market :) Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @riverfall - At worst, you would receive one payment per Reserved Instance that is sold. You might receive fewer is somebody purchases multiple at the same time -- that page says "A transaction can involve one or more Reserved Instances."